# How to create a Custom GUI?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am creating a Minecraft vanilla mini games server and I want to create a custom GUI, but as far as I know there is no way to do this without a Bukkit server. I want to make it so it will `/testfor` a compass in a player's hand. When the player has a compass, it will `/summon` a donkey without a saddle, and with a chest on the player's head. When the player left clicks with the compass, it will open the donkey's chest GUI. Then, I want to make it so there is already items in the chest, but an unsure how.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I tried doing it on my own and than looking it up but i found no answer to my problem

Answer (score 4):

Use `/replaceitem`. It will allow you to set items in the donkey's chest. Then, give each item a custom name. `testfor` it being in a player's inventory, then perform the necessary action