# Minecraft "Chest Menus"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I've been on some servers where if you right click an item, such as a compass, it will open up a chest menu with items that'll execute different things, such as sending you into a game. I was thinking of making something like this, but it would be good if I had an idea what is was called and how to do it.

Comment: It's called a plugin. But usually, bigger servers use their own plugins and don't distribute them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Custom GUI?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263912/how-to-create-a-custom-gui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, such things are only possible by modifying the minecraft code, usually through the use of the Bukkit API. If you want to learn how to make such modifications using the Bukkit API, or maybe find one that has already been made, I'd suggest visiting the [bukkit.org](https://bukkit.org/) website.